# PowerBI embedded dashboard Desktop / Mobile

Tags: html, powerbi, embed, desktop

I want to embed a PowerBI dashboard on a webpage. This works with the classic PowerBI Publish to web for the desktop.

Is there a way that the webpage dynamically switches to the mobile view when accessed from a mobile device?

HTML for Desktop:

```
<iframe width="900" height="700" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNmI1NTk0MmYtMmQzNy00N2IzLWFiYWQtY2QxNGUzNTI4YzA5IiwidCI6IjE3NTQxNmE2LTI2YzgtNGRmZi1iNWUwLTIwNTk5YjMzODk1ZCIsImMiOjl9" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Publish to web does not support phone (mobile) view. If you are embedding using Power BI Embedded API, you can control the layout by specifying `MobilePortrait` or `MobileLandscape` layout types in the configuration. Or you can change this later, using following JavaScript code:

```
const newSettings = {
    layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobileLandscape
};

report.updateSettings(newSettings);
```

For more information you can see [Embed a report in mobile layout](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-For-Mobile#embed-a-report-in-mobile-layout) article.